# Database querying: GROUPing extracting first and last row

Tags: postgresql, group-by, window-functions, postgresql-9.4, gaps-and-islands

I have the following "starting" query:

```
select fecha as date,velocidad as speed, velocidad>100 as overspeed 
from reports.avl_historico_354898046636089 
where fecha between '2017-04-19 00:00:00-03' and '2017-04-20 00:00:00-03'
and velocidad>2 and ignicion=1
order by fecha;
```

Which yields the following output:

```
date                  speed overspeed

2017-04-19 11:35:41+00,16,f
2017-04-19 11:37:01+00,24,f
2017-04-19 11:37:41+00,72,f
2017-04-19 11:38:21+00,82,f
2017-04-19 11:39:01+00,13,f
2017-04-19 11:39:41+00,68,f
2017-04-19 11:40:21+00,23,f
2017-04-19 11:41:01+00,57,f
2017-04-19 11:41:41+00,97,f
2017-04-19 11:42:21+00,96,f
2017-04-19 11:43:01+00,102,t
2017-04-19 11:43:41+00,104,t
2017-04-19 11:44:21+00,106,t
2017-04-19 11:45:01+00,109,t
2017-04-19 11:45:41+00,109,t
2017-04-19 11:46:21+00,114,t
2017-04-19 11:47:01+00,56,f
2017-04-19 11:47:28+00,54,f
2017-04-19 11:47:41+00,54,f
2017-04-19 11:48:21+00,54,f
2017-04-19 11:49:01+00,102,t
2017-04-19 11:49:07+00,104,t
2017-04-19 11:54:21+00,114,t
2017-04-19 11:55:01+00,118,t
2017-04-19 11:55:41+00,115,t
2017-04-19 11:56:21+00,111,t
2017-04-19 11:57:01+00,85,f
2017-04-19 11:57:41+00,45,f
2017-04-19 11:58:21+00,29,f
2017-04-19 12:00:35+00,4,f
2017-04-19 12:00:36+00,4,f
...
```

And I've been trying to work with `LAG/LEAD` to get the first/last date for each group of rows where the `overspeed` column is `TRUE`, but I haven't been able to achieve the desired results, which could be like this:

```
start                     stop
2017-04-19 11:43:01+00    2017-04-19 11:46:21+00
2017-04-19 11:49:01+00    2017-04-19 11:56:21+00
```

Any ideas on how to get such output would be appreciated.

Original table DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE avl_historico_354898046636089 (
    fecha timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    latitud double precision DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    longitud double precision DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    altitud double precision DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    velocidad double precision DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    cog double precision DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    nsat integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    tipo character(1),
    utc_hora time without time zone,
    fix_fecha date,
    imei bigint NOT NULL,
    registro timestamp with time zone,
    input1 integer DEFAULT 0,
    input2 integer DEFAULT 0,
    input3 integer DEFAULT 0,
    input4 integer DEFAULT 0,
    hdop double precision,
    adc double precision DEFAULT (-99),
    ignicion integer DEFAULT 1,
    adc2 double precision,
    power integer,
    driverid integer,
    ibutton2 integer,
    ibutton3 integer,
    ibutton4 integer,
    trailerid integer,
    adc3 double precision,
    adc4 double precision,
    horometro bigint,
    odometro bigint,
    panico integer DEFAULT 0,
    bateria double precision,
    bateriaint double precision
);
```

Comment: please update out put with result of `copy (select fecha as date,velocidad as speed, velocidad>100 as overspeed 
from reports.avl_historico_354898046636089 
where fecha between '2017-04-19 00:00:00-03' and '2017-04-20 00:00:00-03'
and velocidad>2 and ignicion=1
order by fecha) to stdin delimiter ',';`

Comment: in short, try window functions `min, max(date) over (partition by overspeed)` and then `lag lead` to combine em

Comment: @VaoTsun just changed the output format and included the DDL

Comment: The DDL isn't enough, we need test data. Anyway, I've shown you how it should work in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a GROUPING AND WINDOW sample.

NOTE I've edited some result just to make it smaller.

> ```
> create table test (fecha timestamp, velocidad int, overspeed  bool);
> insert into test values
> ('2017-04-19 20:18:17+00',  77,  FALSE),
> ('2017-04-19 20:18:57+00',  96,  FALSE),
> ('2017-04-19 20:19:37+00',  108, TRUE),
> ('2017-04-19 20:20:17+00',  111, TRUE),
> ('2017-04-19 20:20:57+00',  114, TRUE),
> ('2017-04-19 20:21:37+00',  112, TRUE),
> ('2017-04-19 20:22:17+00',  108, FALSE),
> ('2017-04-19 20:22:57+00',  107, FALSE),
> ('2017-04-19 20:23:37+00', 113, FALSE),
> ('2017-04-19 20:24:17+00', 116, TRUE),
> ('2017-04-19 20:24:57+00',  111, TRUE),
> ('2017-04-19 20:25:37+00',  113, TRUE),
> ('2017-04-19 20:26:17+00',  115, FALSE),
> ('2017-04-19 20:26:28+00',  115, FALSE),
> ('2017-04-19 20:26:57+00',  115, TRUE),
> ('2017-04-19 20:27:37+00',  115, TRUE),
> ('2017-04-19 20:27:58+00',  60,  FALSE);
> ```

> ```
> with ResetPoint as
> (
>     select fecha, velocidad, overspeed,
>            case when lag(overspeed) over (order by fecha) = overspeed then null else 1 end as reset
>     from test
> )
>     --= Set a group each time overspeed changes
>     , SetGroup as
>     (
>         select fecha, velocidad, overspeed, 
>                count(reset) over (order by fecha) as grp
>         from ResetPoint
>     )
>     select *
>     from SetGroup;
> ```
>
> ```
> fecha               | velocidad | overspeed | grp
> :------------------ | --------: | :-------- | --:
> 2017-04-19 20:18:17 |        77 | f         |   1
> 2017-04-19 20:18:57 |        96 | f         |   1
> 2017-04-19 20:19:37 |       108 | t         |   2
> 2017-04-19 20:20:17 |       111 | t         |   2
> 2017-04-19 20:20:57 |       114 | t         |   2
> 2017-04-19 20:21:37 |       112 | t         |   2
> 2017-04-19 20:22:17 |       108 | f         |   3
> 2017-04-19 20:22:57 |       107 | f         |   3
> 2017-04-19 20:23:37 |       113 | f         |   3
> 2017-04-19 20:24:17 |       116 | t         |   4
> 2017-04-19 20:24:57 |       111 | t         |   4
> 2017-04-19 20:25:37 |       113 | t         |   4
> 2017-04-19 20:26:17 |       115 | f         |   5
> 2017-04-19 20:26:28 |       115 | f         |   5
> 2017-04-19 20:26:57 |       115 | t         |   6
> 2017-04-19 20:27:37 |       115 | t         |   6
> 2017-04-19 20:27:58 |        60 | f         |   7
> ```

> ```
> --= Set a reset point each time overspeed changes
> --
> with ResetPoint as
> (
>     select fecha, velocidad, overspeed,
>            case when lag(overspeed) over (order by fecha) = overspeed then null else 1 end as reset
>     from test
> )
>     --= Set a group each time overspeed changes
>     , SetGroup as
>     (
>         select fecha, velocidad, overspeed, 
>                count(reset) over (order by fecha) as grp
>         from ResetPoint
>     )
>     --= Retruns MIN and MAX date of each group
>     select grp, min(fecha) as Start, max(fecha) as End
>     from SetGroup
>     group by grp;
> ```
>
> ```
> grp | start               | end                
> --: | :------------------ | :------------------
>   4 | 2017-04-19 20:24:17 | 2017-04-19 20:25:37
>   1 | 2017-04-19 20:18:17 | 2017-04-19 20:18:57
>   5 | 2017-04-19 20:26:17 | 2017-04-19 20:26:28
>   3 | 2017-04-19 20:22:17 | 2017-04-19 20:23:37
>   6 | 2017-04-19 20:26:57 | 2017-04-19 20:27:37
>   2 | 2017-04-19 20:19:37 | 2017-04-19 20:21:37
>   7 | 2017-04-19 20:27:58 | 2017-04-19 20:27:58
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=c0f1d00c3e17c0a488a9b26a5fe3c663)*

Comment: same comment as in the answer from Erwin Brandstetter, but I'll try to adjust it to the actual table to compare execution plans and timing

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT grp, min(date) AS start, max(date) AS stop
FROM (

    SELECT date, speed, count(is_reset) OVER () AS grp
    FROM (

        SELECT
          date,
          speed,
          CASE
            WHEN overspeed <> lag(overspeed) OVER (ORDER BY date) THEN 1
          END AS is_reset
        FROM (

            select fecha as date,velocidad as speed, velocidad>100 as overspeed 
            from reports.avl_historico_354898046636089 
            where fecha between '2017-04-19 00:00:00-03' and '2017-04-20 00:00:00-03'
            and velocidad>2 and ignicion=1

        ) AS t

    ) AS t2

) AS t3
GROUP BY grp;
```

Comment: There's something wrong, as this query only creates a single row of output and, should be at least 2 with the data provided in the question (output: `8, 2017-04-19 11:07:06+00, 2017-04-19 20:39:54+00`)

Comment: I don't believe you, prove it.

Comment: Still don't believe you.

Comment: What else should I provide?

Comment: Dump the data from reports.avl_historico_354898046636089 into the question. Show me the output you want. You can use COPY to do it quickly

Answer (score 1):

This can be simpler. Subtract two `row_number()` calls:

```
SELECT min(date) AS start
     , max(date) AS stop
FROM  (
   SELECT date, overspeed
        , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY date)
        - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY overspeed ORDER BY date) AS grp
   FROM tbl  -- result of your starting query
   ) sub
WHERE  overspeed
GROUP  BY grp
ORDER  BY grp;
```

The 1st generates a running number over all, the 2nd partitioned by `overspeed`. When you subtract the second from the first, each group in ends up with same group numbers, distinct per partition.

Then filter the ones with `overspeed` in the outer query and take min & max per group. Voilá.

Detailed explanation:

- [Grouping or Window](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166374/grouping-or-window/166397#166397)

Aside: a *timestamp* is not a *date*. That's a confusing column name.

### Integrate your subquery

Addressing your comment. Replace `tbl` with your original query as subquery like this:

```
SELECT min(date) AS start
     , max(date) AS stop
FROM  (
   SELECT date, overspeed
        , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY date)
        - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY overspeed ORDER BY date) AS grp
   FROM (
      SELECT fecha AS date, velocidad AS speed, velocidad > 100 AS overspeed 
      FROM   reports.avl_historico_354898046636089 
      WHERE  fecha >= '2017-04-19 00:00:00-03'  -- typically, you include the lower
      AND    fecha <  '2017-04-20 00:00:00-03'  -- and exclude the upper bound
      AND    velocidad > 2
      AND    ignicion = 1
      -- drop the now useless inner ORDER BY
      ) sub1
   ) sub2
WHERE  overspeed
GROUP  BY grp
ORDER  BY grp;
```

Then you can simplify some more:

```
SELECT min(fecha) AS start
     , max(fecha) AS stop
FROM  (
   SELECT fecha, velocidad > 100 AS overspeed 
        , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY fecha)
        - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY velocidad > 100 ORDER BY fecha) AS grp
   FROM   reports.avl_historico_354898046636089 
   WHERE  fecha >= '2017-04-19 00:00:00-03'
   AND    fecha <  '2017-04-20 00:00:00-03'
   AND    velocidad > 2
   AND    ignicion = 1
   ) sub
WHERE  overspeed
GROUP  BY grp
ORDER  BY grp;
```

Comment: sounds quite a simple answers, but it takes the output of my original query as if it was an actual table, which is not the real life scenario

Comment: @gvasquez; I added advice above.

Comment: now works perfectly as expected, but narrowing down the actual use case I had to add `avg(velocidad)` to the selected columns and, `HAVING max(fecha)-min(fecha) > '2 minutes'::interval` as an extra clause to complete fullfil the request. Thanks a lot Erwin